# Validating "Parallel" JSON Arrays

Tags: python, json, pydantic

I am trying to use pydantic to validate JSON that is being returned in a "parallel" array format. Namely, there is an array defining the column names/types followed by an array of "rows" (this is similar to how pandas handles `df.to_json(orient='split')` seen [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html))

```json
{
    "columns": [
        "sensor",
        "value",
        "range"
    ],
    "data": [
        [
            "a",
            1,
            {"low": 1, "high": 2}
        ],
        [
            "b",
            2,
            {"low": 0, "high": 2}
        ]
    ]
}
```

I know that I could do this:

```py
class ValueRange(BaseModel):
    low: int
    high: int

class Response(BaseModel):
    columns: Tuple[Literal['sensor'], Literal['value'], Literal['range']]
    data: List[Tuple[str, int, ValueRange]]
```

But this has a few downsides:

- After parsing, it doesn't allow for an association of the data with the column names. So, you have to do everything by index. Ideally, I would like to parse a response into a `List[Row]` and then be able to do things like `response.data[0].sensor`.
- It hardcodes the column order.
- It doesn't allow for responses that have variable columns in the responses. For example, the same endpoint could also return the following:

```
{
    "columns": ["sensor", "value"],
    "data": [
        ["a", 1],
        ["b", 2]
    ]
}
```

At first I thought that I could use pydantic's [discriminated unions](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/types/#discriminated-unions-aka-tagged-unions), but I'm not seeing how to do this across arrays.

Anyone know of the best approach for validating this type of data? (I'm currently using pydantic, but am open to other libraries if it makes sense).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR

A very interesting use case for a [custom validator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators).

```py
from collections.abc import Sequence
from typing import Literal, Optional

from pydantic import BaseModel, validator
from pydantic.fields import Field


Column = Literal["sensor", "value", "range"]


class ValueRange(BaseModel):
    low: int
    high: int


class DataPoint(BaseModel):
    sensor: str
    value: int
    range: Optional[ValueRange]


class Response(BaseModel):
    columns: Optional[tuple[Column, ...]] = Field(exclude=True, repr=False)
    data: list[DataPoint]

    @validator("columns", pre=True)
    def ensure_distinct(cls, v: object) -> object:
        if isinstance(v, Sequence) and len(v) != len(set(v)):
            raise ValueError("`columns` must all be distinct")
        return v

    @validator("data", pre=True, each_item=True)
    def parse_nested_sequence(
        cls,
        v: object,
        values: dict[str, object],
    ) -> object:
        if not isinstance(v, Sequence):
            return v
        columns = values.get("columns")
        if not isinstance(columns, Sequence):
            raise TypeError(
                "If `data` items are provided as a sequences, "
                "the `columns` must be present as a sequence."
            )
        if len(columns) != len(v):
            raise ValueError(
                "`data` item must be the same length as `columns`"
            )
        return dict(zip(columns, v))
```

---

## Explanation

### Schema

First we need to set up the models to reflect the schema we want to have *after* parsing and validation are complete.

Since you mentioned that you would like the `data` field in the response model to be a list of model instances corresponding to a certain schema, we need to define that schema. From your example it seems to need at least the fields `sensor`, `value` and `range`. The `range` field should be its own model once again. You also mentioned that `range` should be optional, so we'll encode that too.

The actual top-level `Response` model will still have the `columns` field because we will need that for validation later on. But we can hide that field from the string representation and the [exporter methods](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/exporting_models/) like `dict` and `json`. To communicate the variable number of elements in that `columns` tuple, we'll change the annotation a bit.

Here are the models I would suggest:

```py
from collections.abc import Sequence
from typing import Literal, Optional

from pydantic import BaseModel, validator
from pydantic.fields import Field


Column = Literal["sensor", "value", "range"]


class ValueRange(BaseModel):
    low: int
    high: int


class DataPoint(BaseModel):
    sensor: str
    value: int
    range: Optional[ValueRange]


class Response(BaseModel):
    columns: Optional[tuple[Column, ...]] = Field(exclude=True, repr=False)
    data: list[DataPoint]

    ...  # more code
```

---

### Field types and parameters

To hide `columns` we can use the appropriate parameters of the [`Field` constructor](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/schema/#field-customization). Making it `Optional` (default will be `None`) means we could still initialize an instance of `Response` without it, but we would then of course be forced to provide the `data` list in the correct format (as dictionaries or `DataPoint` instances).

Since we used `tuple[Column, ...]` as the annotation for `columns`, the elements could be in any order, which is what you wanted, but it could also theoretically be of arbitrary length and contain a bunch of duplicates. The Python typing system does not provide any elegant tool to define the type in a way that indicates that all elements of the tuple must be distinct. We could of course construct a huge type union of all permutations of the literal values that should be valid, but this is hardly practical.

---

### Validators

Instead I would suggest a very simple validator to do this check for us:

```py
...

class Response(BaseModel):
    columns: Optional[tuple[Column, ...]] = Field(exclude=True, repr=False)
    data: list[DataPoint]

    @validator("columns", pre=True)
    def ensure_distinct(cls, v: object) -> object:
        if isinstance(v, Sequence) and len(v) != len(set(v)):
            raise ValueError("`columns` must all be distinct")
        return v

    ...  # more code
```

The `pre=True` is actually important here, but only in conjunction with the second validator. That one is much more interesting because it is supposed to bring those columns together with the sequences of data. Here is what I propose:

```py
...

class Response(BaseModel):
    columns: Optional[tuple[Column, ...]] = Field(exclude=True, repr=False)
    data: list[DataPoint]

    @validator("columns", pre=True)
    def ensure_distinct(cls, v: object) -> object:
        if isinstance(v, Sequence) and len(v) != len(set(v)):
            raise ValueError("`columns` must all be distinct")
        return v

    @validator("data", pre=True, each_item=True)
    def parse_nested_sequence(
        cls,
        v: object,
        values: dict[str, object],
    ) -> object:
        if not isinstance(v, Sequence):
            return v
        columns = values.get("columns")
        if not isinstance(columns, Sequence):
            raise TypeError(
                "If `data` items are provided as a sequences, "
                "the `columns` must be present as a sequence."
            )
        if len(columns) != len(v):
            raise ValueError(
                "`data` item must be the same length as `columns`"
            )
        return dict(zip(columns, v))
```

The [`pre=True`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/#pre-and-per-item-validators) on both validators ensures that they are run *before* the default validators for those field types (otherwise we would immediately get a validation error from your example `data`). Field validators are always called **in the order the fields were defined**, so we ensured that our custom `columns` validator is called before our custom `data` validator.

That order also allows us to access the output of our `columns` validator in the `values` dictionary of our `data` validator.

The [`each_item=True`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/#pre-and-per-item-validators) flag changes the behavior of the validator so that it is applied to each individual element of the `data` list as opposed to the entire list. That means with our example data the `v` argument will always be a single "sub-list" (e.g. `["a", 1]`).

If the value to validate is not of a sequence type, we don't bother with it. It will then be handled appropriately by the default field validator. If it *is* a sequence, we need to make sure that `columns` is present and also a sequence and that they are of the same length. If those checks pass, we can just zip them, consume that zip into a dictionary and send it on its merry way to the default field validator.

That's all.

---

### Demo

Here is a little demo script:

```py
def main() -> None:
    from pydantic import ValidationError
    print(Response.parse_raw(TEST_JSON_VALID_1).json(indent=2), "\n")
    print(Response.parse_raw(TEST_JSON_VALID_2).json(indent=2), "\n")
    try:
        Response.parse_raw(TEST_JSON_INVALID_1)
    except ValidationError as exc:
        print(exc.json(indent=2), "\n")
    try:
        Response.parse_raw(TEST_JSON_INVALID_2)
    except ValidationError as exc:
        print(exc.json(indent=2), "\n")
    try:
        Response.parse_raw(TEST_JSON_INVALID_3)
    except ValidationError as exc:
        print(exc.json(indent=2))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And here is the test data and its corresponding output:

##### `TEST_JSON_VALID_1`

```json
{
    "columns": [
        "sensor",
        "value",
        "range"
    ],
    "data": [
        [
            "a",
            1,
            {"low": 1, "high": 2}
        ],
        [
            "b",
            2,
            {"low": 0, "high": 2}
        ]
    ]
}
```

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "sensor": "a",
      "value": 1,
      "range": {
        "low": 1,
        "high": 2
      }
    },
    {
      "sensor": "b",
      "value": 2,
      "range": {
        "low": 0,
        "high": 2
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

##### `TEST_JSON_VALID_2` (different order and no `range`)

```json
{
    "columns": ["value", "sensor"],
    "data": [
        [1, "a"],
        [2, "b"]
    ]
}
```

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "sensor": "a",
      "value": 1,
      "range": null
    },
    {
      "sensor": "b",
      "value": 2,
      "range": null
    }
  ]
}
```

##### `TEST_JSON_INVALID_1`

```json
{
    "columns": ["foo", "value"],
    "data": []
}
```

```json
[
  {
    "loc": [
      "columns",
      0
    ],
    "msg": "unexpected value; permitted: 'sensor', 'value', 'range'",
    "type": "value_error.const",
    "ctx": {
      "given": "foo",
      "permitted": [
        "sensor",
        "value",
        "range"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

##### `TEST_JSON_INVALID_2`

```json
{
    "columns": ["value", "value"],
    "data": []
}
```

```json
[
  {
    "loc": [
      "columns"
    ],
    "msg": "`columns` must all be distinct",
    "type": "value_error"
  }
]
```

##### `TEST_JSON_INVALID_3`

```json
{
    "columns": ["sensor", "value"],
    "data": [["a", 1], ["b"]]
}
```

```json
[
  {
    "loc": [
      "data",
      1
    ],
    "msg": "`data` item must be the same length as `columns`",
    "type": "value_error"
  }
]
```